# Printing a drupal 7 user field into a link

Tags: entities, navigation, theming

Ok so my goal here is to allow users to link there social media profiles onto their user pages. So i tried to print the field within an href statement so it would come out as a link.
For example if the value for the field link is http://www.google.com, then it should output the text link with a link to google when clicked.

But it doesnt, it instead outputs the value for the field_link and links it to

Heres what i attempted at:

```
<html>
<a href="<?php print render($user_profile['field_link']); ?>">Link</a>
</html>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Edit:
Ok so this is what it outputs:

```
<a href=" <div class="field field-name-field-link field-type-text field-label-hidden><div class="field-items"><div class="field-item even">http://www.google.com</div></div>  </div> ">
```

But i only want the web address
Please Help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Link field Module](https://drupal.org/project/link):

> The link module can be count to the top 50 modules in Drupal
>   installations and provides a standard custom content field for links.
>   With this module links can be added easily to any content types and
>   profiles and include advanced validating and different ways of storing
>   internal or external links and URLs. It also supports additional link
>   text title, site wide tokens for titles and title attributes, target
>   attributes, css class attribution, static repeating values, input
>   conversion, and many more.

Or better, yet do a search for drupal social media for a number of different modules to do exactly this.

Comment: Thank you so much!! How did i not think of that *facepalm*